# Why is my task in Application_Start() being stopped/cancelled/terminated?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, task-parallel-library, task, background-process

I have the following code in my ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application:

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Trace.WriteLine("Working");
            }
        },
        cancellationToken,
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunningTask,
        TaskScheduler.Current);
}
```

It seems that the task starts running while the application is initialising, runs for a bit, but then it stops. I want to to keep running for as long as the AppDomain is running. What is causing it to stop and isthere anything I can do to stop it from stopping?

Comment: It would help if you posted code that actually made sense. How can your method return a `Task`, when it's declared as `void`-returning? Where is the `cancellationToken` in `LongRunningTask()` coming from? Could you post short (and compiling) code that actually demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I made some mistakes when trying to simplify the code for the sake of brevity. It's difficult to condense an existing complex application into a short snippet. I think I've fixed the code sample above now though.

Answer (score 0):

From code you got, it appears your cancellationToken is null and you have NullRefernceException on your code line:

```
 while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
```

Can you see such exception in logs?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, but that is only because I had oversimplified the code example. I've corrected the code sample now. The task does run and "loops" round the while loop a few times but then it stops.

Comment: `CancellationToken` is a `struct`, so it can never be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the underlying problem was the Glimpse TraceInspector, a side-effect of [this issue](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/248).

Because this was causing an exception to be thrown, the task was being stopped.

I still can't fully explain the detail, but adding this to my Web.config resolved the problem:

```xml
  <glimpse>
    <inspectors>
      <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.Core.Inspector.TraceInspector, Glimpse.Core"/>
      </ignoredTypes>
    </inspectors>
  </glimpse>
```